# Don't show count if zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I made a simple website, where photos can be attached to an entry.
In the photo, you can see that I tried to display how many photos each entry has (blue color)

[image]

but I don't want Rails to display `0` if no image is attached. Here's my code:

```
<span id="anzahl"><%= treatment.paintings.count  %></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use counter cache in your models. The way you are using right now, is not a good practice as it will generate too many sql queries. To avoid this:

### Add a migration:

```
self.up
 add_column :treatment, :paintings_count, :integer, :default => 0

 Treatment.reset_column_information
 Treatment.find_each do |u|
   Treatment.reset_counters u.id, :paintings
 end
end
```

### change in Painting model:

```
  belongs_to :treatment, counter_cache: true
```

#### Then in View:

```
<span id="anzahl"><%= treatment.paintings_count if treatment.paintings_count > 0 %></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
treatment.paintings.count.tap{|count| break (count unless count.zero?)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the code as per the followings

```
<span id="anzahl">
   <% treatment_paintings_count = treatment.paintings.count %>
   <%= treatment_paintings_count unless treatment_paintings_count == 0 %>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the count to determine if it should display

```
<span id="anzahl">
  <%= treatment.paintings.count if treatment.paintings.count > 0 %>
</span>
```